# Elastic Search Painless Script Document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am new to ES, and I am trying to write a search query with aggregations.

While writing the same, I am facing issues with the Painless script.

Where can I get the complete painless script document, which is used in Elastic Search?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask a good question, as this will help the community understand your issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find its docs here: [painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.4/index.html)